# IntRange with flatten , map and flatmap kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, range

Hi im doing atomic kotlin manupulating lists exercise.I need to help understanding the following

```kotlin
val intRange = 1..3

intRange.map { a ->          // [1]
    intRange.map { b -> a to b }
} eq "[" +
    "[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], " +
    "[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)], " +
    "[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]" +
    "]"
```

where do a , b values come from ?

Comment: They're arguments to a function. See [Lambda expressions and anonymous functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions).

Answer (score 1):

1. We have that `val intRange = 1..3` :

This is an IntRange from 1 to 3 (both inclusive)

2. Then we have the first `map`: `intRange.map { a -> ... }`

This map is going to loop through the intRange and it takes a lambda function as a parameter which is this in your case `{ a -> ... }`, `a` will take each time the value of the current `Int` from the `IntRange`, so this lambda function is going to get executed 3 times with `a` having 3 different values (1, 2, 3), and you can call that `a` anything else you want so your function could be like that for example:

```
intRange.map { myValue -> 
    println(myValue) // 1, 2, 3
}
```

and you can even delete `myValue ->` and the variable name will be `it` which is the default name:

```
intRange.map {
    println(it) // 1, 2, 3
}
```

and the same thing for `b`, `a` and `b` are going to take their values from that intRange, they will start from 1 to 3 (1, 2, 3) because the intRange = 1..3, if you change it to this `val intRange = 1..4`, then `a` and `b` are going to start from 1 to 4.